# WebdriverIO - How to add custom headers to all requests

Tags: javascript, typescript, webdriver-io, web-testing, wdio-v6

I need to add custom headers to all requests in order to access the web app which is normally hidden behind corporate proxy and vpn and be able to run E2E tests. As an automation tool we user WebdriverIO. So far I tried to set up custom header in wdio.conf.js file following official wdio documentation (https://webdriver.io/docs/options/) and added headers option inside capabilities in my config file. Unfortunately, this is not working and I still can't connect to our web app. Has anyone tried to add custom headers in wdio.config.js file and run E2E tests?
Contents of my wdio.config.js file are following:

```
        exports.config = {
      runner: 'local',
    
      specs: [
        './src/specs/**/login.spec.ts',
      ],
      // Patterns to exclude.
      exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
      ],
    
      maxInstances: 10,
    
      capabilities: [
        {
          maxInstances: 5,
          browserName: 'chrome',
          acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    
          headers: {
            'REQUIRED-HEADER-KEY': 'HEADER-VALUE'
          },
    
          'goog:chromeOptions': {
            'excludeSwitches': [
              'enable-automation'
            ],
            prefs: {
              'profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications': 1, 
              'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': true, 
              'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false, 
                'default_directory': process.cwd() + '/tmp'
              }
            },
            args: [
              '--disable-gpu',
              '--window-size=1920,1080',
              '--no-sandbox',
              '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
              '--start-maximized',
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way doing this at this time, see [webdriverio/issues/6361](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/6361)

But you can do it with [modheader_selenium](https://github.com/bewisse/modheader_selenium#usage):

`npm install chrome-modheader`

```
const chromeModheader = require('chrome-modheader');
exports.config = {
...
    capabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome',
        "goog:chromeOptions": {
            extensions: [chromeModheader.getExtension()],
        }
    }],
...
    before: function (capabilities, specs) {
        browser.url(chromeModheader.getAddHeaderUrl('YOUR_HEADER', 'YOUR_HEADER_VALUE'));
    },
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you unickq your solution really helped! The only thing that I needed to change in your example was removing chromeOptions (as it gave me an error in wdio - not supported capability) and place the extensions line inside  'goog:chromeOptions': {} block

Comment: You're right. Updated comment with goog:chromeOptions

Answer (score -1):

Can you please see what could be wrong? Thanks

```
const { config } = require('../wdio.conf');
const chromeModheader = require('chrome-modheader');
config.capabilities = [{
maxInstances: 1,
browserName: 'chrome',
'goog:chromeOptions': {
extensions: [chromeModheader.getExtension()],
enter code here
'excludeSwitches': [
  'enable-automation',
  '--disable-infobars',
  '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
  '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
  '--no-sandbox',
],

before: function (capabilities, specs) {
  browser.url(chromeModheader.getAddHeaderUrl('X-Captcha-Override', 'disable'));
},
}
}];
exports.config = config;
```

Request failed with status 500 due to session not created: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: cannot process extension #1
[0-0] from unknown error: cannot base64 decode
[0-0] Build info: version: '4.4.0', revision: 'e5c75ed026a'

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33449213)